# Crear Trigger que devuelva producto a inventario al actualizar un estado

Tags: mysql, trigger

Buen dia gente, necesito la forma de devolver un producto al stock por el cambio de estado de este en el detalle_asignacion, el sistema es de pañolero-bodega, se asignan herramientas quedando en estado PENDIENTE, y cuando se devuelven queda en estado ENTREGADO, ya cree trigger que me descuenta inventario y que al borrar una fila del detalle me suma al inventario, pero me falta que al actualizar a estado = ENTREGADO se vuelva a sumar el producto al inventario.

Si me pudieran dar una manito mi gente, no se si estará mal formulada la consulta. Es en MySql.

Lo raro es que no me acusa error en el codigo al momento de ejecutarlo, pero en sistema me sale que no me reconoce la columna id_estado. El sistema esta en scriptcase.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DEVOLUCION_STOCK_AU 
AFTER UPDATE ON detalle_asignacion FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE producto
SET producto.stock = producto.stock + detalle_asignacion.cantidad
WHERE producto.n_serie = OLD.n_serie AND detalle_asignacion.id_estado = NEW.id_estado;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Esteban. Por favor, pon el código como texto, en vez de capturas de imagen. El texto es más fácil de analizar y de reproducir. Dinos también cuál es el problema o error con el actual código. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Parece que lo que quieres es: `WHERE producto.n_serie = OLD.n_serie AND NEW.id_estado='ENTREGADO';`